# Regressing over a data frame matrix without intercept using lm

Tags: r

I would like to regress over a data frame matrix using lm without the intercept. If your matrix is stored as a data frame, you can simply call lm(matrix) and the first column is assumed to be the dependent variable while the rest are taken as the independent variables, with the regression including an intercept. My question is: how do I efficiently do the same if I want to regress without including the intercept?

Minimal working example:

```
mat <- matrix(c(2, 4, 3, 1, 5, 7, 3, 5, 30), nrow=3, ncol=3)
mat <- data.frame(mat)
lm(mat)
```

outputs a regression with an intercept term

Comment: Try `lm(X1 ~ . + 0,data=mat)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "efficent".

If you mean *syntactically* brief/efficient, then I think the most elegant way is do provide the formula directly as @nicola shows in the comments (`lm(X1 ~ . + 0, data = mat)`).

If you mean removing the intercept programatically (programatically efficient, I guess), then the below code will do that.

```
mat <- matrix(c(2, 4, 3, 1, 5, 7, 3, 5, 30), nrow=3, ncol=3)
mat <- data.frame(mat)

lm(update(as.formula(mat), . ~ . - 1), data = mat)
#
#Call:
#lm(formula = update(as.formula(mat), . ~ . - 1), data = mat)
# 
#Coefficients:
#     X2       X3  
# 0.9364  -0.1144
```

Note, that when you call `lm(mat)`, `lm` will try to coerce `mat` to a formula object (try to run `as.formula(mat)`) and use that formula. As you can see (and have noted), this automatically selects the first column as the dependent variable and the remaining as explanatory variables. All we need to do then, is updating that formula to not include the intercept using `update`.

Comment: Perfect, thank you for this and accepted as the solution

Comment: @r_master No problem and Thanks. You can of course also write  `. + 0` instead of `. - 1` on the right hand side of the formula  if you prefer (I did not know this before). I actually think `0 + .` gives the code a more clear meaning.